# Simple Docker Project / Process and Save JPEG - Use Volume?

Tags: python, docker, image-processing, virtualbox, docker-volume

Im learning Docker. And I don't really get the hang of docker volumes.
So I set a simple task for me to understand it:

I create a Container with a python script that resizes a JPEG

for example:

```
from PIL import Image

from resizeimage import resizeimage


with open('test-image.jpeg', 'r+b') as f:
    with Image.open(f) as image:
        cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [200, 100])
        cover.save('test-image-cover.jpeg', image.format)
```

Where do I put the Input File ?
Should I create a Volume or a Bind Mount and put the JPEG File there?

Im running Docker on a Virtual Machine ( Standard Docker Toolbox Installation on Win 10) Where do I find the resized Files on the Volumes?

Right now I don't really care if the File is overwritten, if the app is running on server and two users use the container at the same time.

**What is the simplest way to input /process / output a file with a python script running in a container?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is use volumes against local paths:

- Create local path /tmp/myfiles
- put test-image in /tmp/myfiles
- Ensure that your script gets absolute path `with open('/tmp/myfilesdocker/test-image.jpeg', 'r+b') as f:`
- run container `docker run -v /tmp/myfiles:/tmp/myfilesdocker python`

It's the easiest volume. Your local path `/tmp/myfiles` is mounted against the container `/tmp/myfilesdocker`path. You can create the resized image in this path also.

Easiest way to your *hello world* purpose.